# What does it mean when commentators say batsman did not offer a shot to LBW?

Tags: cricket

I have often heard when a batsman is adjudged LBW, if he did not play any shot, the commentators mention that everytime specirically. For example, the batsman is out! He did not offer a shot to this ball!

What does this mean? Is there a law that states anything regarding batsman not offering shot when the ball hits pad? Or is it easier for umpire to give the batsman LBW if he did not offer a shot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the normal laws for an LBW dismissal, the ball must impact the batsman inline with the stumps to be considered to be out LBW.

However, if the batsman makes no genuine attempt to play a shot at the ball, the ball does **not** have to impact inline with the stumps, though it must still impact on the off-side of the stumps.

[MCC Laws of Cricket: Law 36 - LBW](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/leg-before-wicket)

> **36.1.4**
>
> the point of impact, even if above the level of the bails,
>
> either is between wicket and wicket
>
> or **if the striker has made no genuine attempt to play the ball with the bat, is between wicket and wicket or outside the line of the off stump.**

[Handy MCC Animation](https://youtu.be/Dk1-8NtAavA?t=73)